# angular 5, subject.next(value) does not fire

Tags: rxjs, angular5

I have a problem trying to pass values into my subject and subscribing to it from another component. Here is my code that is supposed to pass my value into an observable.

```js
private pdfLink = new Subject<string>();
pdfLinkCast = this.pdfLink.asObservable();

getPdfById(id: string): void {
  this.httpClient.get<any>(this.apiUrl + id + '/pdf', this.httpOptions).subscribe((pdf) => {
    // this prints
    console.log(pdf);

    // not sure if this is working as expected
    this.pdfLink.next(pdf.url);
  });
}
```

In my component I subscribe to it on ngOnInit as follows:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription.add(this.someService.pdfLinkCast.subscribe((pdf) => {
    // these do not print for some reason
    console.log('hello world');
    console.log(pdf);
  }));
}
```

Comment: Most likely you call `this.pdfLink.next(pdf.url);` before you subscribe to `pdfLinkCast`. You can try using `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of `Subject` but be aware that it's not the same thing.

Comment: @martin thanks for the help, but i'm afraid it didn't work. apparently the problem was because this service is located in a child module that is providing for the parent module where the component lies